# What is this "custom badge here..." thing in the badge tracker all about?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

While selecting a new badge to track, I came across something odd on the badge tracker gui:

[image]

I'm looking specifically at this part:

[image]

I've never noticed it before. (And I go through the badge tracker *a lot*.) It doesn't actually seem to work; I still can't track a custom badge after entering one.

What's the deal behind this? Is it an easter egg? Something related to the [recent cyber attack on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/16/security-update/?cb=1)? Something else?

Comment: Looks like it's for a custom tag badge, though the spot for tracking tag badges is different from the one for tracking regular badges. I think this is an internal test that accidentally leaked through onto a public site.

Comment: (By the way, I don't see this on Meta.)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog strange... this seems to show up on every site I visit (including MSE). You may be right about this being a test though.

Comment: I don't see this on a half dozen sites that I checked.

Comment: Looks like A/B testing for tracking tag badge from the dialog. On the other hand, can you still change the tracked tag badge [from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5BEc.png)?

Comment: @NoDistractionWizard yes, I can still change the badge by selecting one that's already existing.

Comment: Is this related to [How can a tag badge for  be tracked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382516/4642212)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I don't think so, this is about normal badges and that was related to tag badges.